# Scrivener: link files to different folders?

Tags: scrivener

Lets say you had two folders in your Research folder and you want a file to be "shared" or linked between folders: the file appears in both folders, but editing one file also changes the other file, since they are the same file, just being linked to from different folders.

Is something like that possible in Scrivener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't share a single item across multiple folders. But perhaps you could use collections to create the kind of organization you want.

You can add any item to any number of collections.

You can also create a Saved Search collection that will dynamically update to include any item that satisfies its search criteria. Then you can use keywords or other features to move items in and out of the dynamic collection.